# Fedora 30 can't boot: faild to start up manager

Tags: fedora, systemd, linux-kernel, init

I newly installed Fedora 30 on a machine then I installed Oracle Database 12c and restored a really big dump (took two days). Then, I installed samba server and shared a folder with that.

After that, I rebooted the system for the first time, but it didn't boot up saying:

```
[!!!!!!] Failed to start up manager
```

and nothing else (the system freezes and doesn't respond to any key).

I can currently get a root shell by using `rd.break` kernel parameter and chrroting to sysroot, but I don't have networking and I can't use `systemctl`.

I also ran `fsck` on the computer's disk (using live os) and it says there is no error in filesystem.

I also found the code generating this error in systemd source code [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/c40bd28419ca02718360d016c47f4ac5495ed0ea/src/core/main.c#L2692).

**How can I boot my system normally, get networking and `systemctl` working**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the answer myself.

After removing the `quiet` kernel option it showed some errors about the SELinux contexts.

The problem was the `selinux` kernel module.

I started the system with `selinux=0` kernel option in grub to prevent selinux from loading and it worked!